# SSL on all the ports

Tags: ssl, dns, subdomain

In my Apache, I have 1 ssl cert verified, I want to use it on all the ports.

For example if one user connects to https://subdomain.domain.com

It works flawlessly but when they try to connect to https://subdomain.domain.com:51104 then it gives red mark.

is there any code or way that i can apply so that anyone connect to server with any port,

the cert will work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what the red mark means? SSL can be ran on any port as long as its bidirectional so the error you get is going to be important to answering this question. A wildcard cert would allow you to ise a subdomain so the port shouldnt be an issue in any way. Post the errror by clicking the red x and checking the webserver logs for a more exacr answer.

Comment: Like this...SSL works perfectly on normal page or sub page on the given subdomain (got SSL for it) http://i.imgur.com/gsX6nvf.png but on the same subdomains on a different port, it gives red cross http://i.imgur.com/vajeqTY.png

Comment: Right, but clicking on the red x will give you the error that is causing the issue,thats what im intreasted in.

Comment: Well the issue is clear, your going to need a wildcard ssl cert and I reccommend you get one with better security features or at least fix your ssl config for that vhost. The card you have coverz subdomains but not port changes for one reason or the other.

Comment: I just bought this - gogetssl.com/comodo-ssl-certificates/comodo-positive-ssl-wildcard/